How can I signin/signup users with phone number in an Expo React Native app?
Problem
Module '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member 'RecaptchaVerifier'.ts(2305)

After following the steps from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?authuser=0&hl=en#use-invisible-recaptcha section, I am getting the error above.
Not sure what I am missing... I updated the packages and double checked the docs but found no way to get around this. I don't have Apple developer account and not planning to get one soon so I can't use the silent notification service thing from Apple. I need this invisible reCaptcha.
Getting the confirmation code
     .....
     ...

     const confirmation = await signInWithPhoneNumber(
          FIREBASE_AUTH,
          phoneNumber,
          RecaptchaVerifier
        );

    ...
    .....

RecaptchaVerifier is failing on me.
I did some research and found out that expo-firebase-recaptcha is deprecated. It seems that the Firebase docs has the only sensible way of doing this.
What I understood from this reCaptcha from Firebase is that it works as it is invisible(making the size invisible of the View container). So users don't have interact with it and Firebase handles that in the back. Users only receive an OTP and they can go ahead, sign in with phone number or create an account.
I am new to this technology and appreciate all the help.

react-native-firebase is not the same thing as the Firebase Web Client SDK (firebase) that your above documentation link points to.
You will want to follow the RNF's docs for phone authentication.
If interested, I wrote this article about the difference between RNF and the Firebase Web Client SDK and Expo/RN.
